# React-native and SPA like architecture

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to build a screen that has a top navigation bar, and a bottom navigation bar. But I only want the view between those to change, much like a spa. Is this achievable in react-native?

Im using nativebase and react-native-router-flux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve using this library https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation

And also follow this tutorial
https://www.codementor.io/blessingoraz/understanding-navigation-in-react-native-a3wlcxmzu